# Is there a way to restore a DB in SQL 2005 from LDF only?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Our DB server fell, and we need to restore some of it's DB's. We can find only the LDF file of the needed DB. Is there a tool that can use that for restoring? We're using SQL 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You will also need the .mdf

Answer (score 0):

The LDF file is the transaction log, I doubt you can get anything useful out of it alone.

You do have backups, right?